# Type Error: predict() missing 1 required positional argument: 'X'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I seem to get this error all the time with this code. It is from a YouTube tutorial, and I seem to have gotten everything right.

Here is the code:

```
import sklearn
from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris()

X = iris.data
y = iris.target

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size = .5)

from sklearn import tree
my_classifier = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier

my_classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)


predictions = my_Classifier.predict(X_test)

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
print(accuracy_score)
```

Comment: You need to initiate the classifier: `my_classifier = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()`

Comment: OK. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: It also says that predict() missing 1 required positional argument: 'X'

Comment: You have a typo: `my_Classifier` you wrote **C** instead of **c**. You capitalized it.

Comment: Last question: It says that TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

Comment: When you change your code into `my_classifier = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()`, it should be fine. Reproduced the code, it runs fine.

Comment: Thanks all for your help!